# How to make changes to Spark Laravel Billing page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I am trying to make changes to the Spark Laravel BillingPortal.vue page. After making a change I know the the app.js is being compiled but I see no change in the billing page.

I have cleared the cache in Laravel and the browser and still not luck.

I can completely delete all code on the page and still nothing happens. It is still the same in the browser.

Please tell me how to change this file.

Answer (score 2):

The BillingPortal.vue file compiles into Spark's `/public/js/app.js` file, so in order to see any updates you'll need to rebuild Spark's JavaScript separately from your application's assets.

`cd vendor/laravel/spark-stripe` (or `vendor/laravel/spark-paddle` if you're using Spark Paddle)

`npm install`

`npm run dev`

That being said, it's not recommended that you make changes to Composer packages because the changes will be overwritten when the package is updated.  Instead choose one of the options mentioned [in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080696/safely-edit-a-third-party-composer-vendor-package-in-laravel-prevent-losing)