# How to modify Laravel Spark sidebar view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I'm using Spark for the subscription in Laravel for the first time and now I want to modify some changes on the Spark left sidebar.

[image]

I have published the [Spark View](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.x/spark-stripe/customization.html#localization) file using the below command but don't know how to place some HTML on the left sidebar.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=spark-lang
```

Comment: Did you make changes to the view you published and they don't show up?

Comment: I'm not sure I want to place some HTML in the sidebar. After publishing the view file, I'm getting this HTML in app.blade.php. `<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    @inertia

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.translations = <?php echo $translations; ?>;

        {!! file_get_contents($jsPath) !!}
    </script>
</body>`

Comment: All the HTML is coming from the `/vendor/laravel/spark-stripe/resources/js/Pages/BillingPortal.vue` file

Comment: From the [documentation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.x/spark-stripe/customization.html): `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=spark-views` to publish the views, `--tag=spark-lang` publishes the localization files. Views should then be available in `resources/views/vendor/spark/`

Comment: Yes. The view is available and has an app blade file in the spark folder. In-app blade having this HTML `<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    @inertia

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.translations = <?php echo $translations; ?>;

        {!! file_get_contents($jsPath) !!}
    </script>
</body>` but how to add some html in sidebar?

Comment: I don't have a Spark license so I could only give this rudimentary tip. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily change the HTML, but you can modify the billing portal text in the `resources/lang/spark/en.json` file.  That file is intended to be used for translations, but in a pinch you can use it to change the default text.

If you need to change the HTML, you can find it in this Vue file: `vendor/laravel/spark-stripe/resources/js/Pages/BillingPortal.vue` (assuming that you're using Stripe).

However, any changes to that file will be overwritten when you update the package, so the best practice is to copy/fork the package. See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43589206/1379025) for more details.